# How to adjust pd.df.plot() for this dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My work has me learning pandas, and to practice I created the following dataframe out of a large data set. My question is how do I plot it such that I have years on the x axis, the values (profits) on the y axis, and a line for each age group in the plot?

|  | 2011 | 2012 | 2013 | 2014 | 2015 | 2016 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **Youth (<25)** | 508522 | 500161 | 950980 | 567125 | 1191114 | 656690 |
| **Adults (35-64)** | 1278031 | 1336260 | 2737478 | 3416871 | 3436847 | 4116095 |
| **Young Adults (25-34)** | 1085579 | 1108066 | 2252986 | 1839782 | 2880608 | 2219740 |
| **Seniors (64+)** | 9169 | 7506 | 17764 | 40309 | 19994 | 43423 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Transpose the dataframe using [`.T`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transpose.html) and call [`.plot()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html)

```py
>>> df.T.plot()
```

[image: plot]